# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (default-cli) on project projectName:

Tags: java

I am facing error when I try to run mvn enforcer:enforce -X
in local system.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce
> (default-cli) on project projectName: No rules are configured. Use the
> skip flag if you want to disable execution. -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce
> (default-cli) on project projectName: No rules are configured. Use the
> skip flag if you want to disable execution.

Comment: Providing the snippet of your pom.xml would help to understand the problem bit more.